# Address locator returns no objects found

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geocoding, address

Trying to build an address locator for the following feature case

[image]

But unfortunately when I use find locations it finds no object

[image]

What might be the issue here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried going into the Geolocator's properties, and switching the field "Match with no zones" to Yes?

This will make it so you do not have to type out the full address, such as "3 Yaum Al Ard Ramallah"

[image]

Comment: Thanks Goerge, without switching the field "Match with no zones"  I should enter the full name but now its working fine even if i haven't entered the full name